# javascript Redirect submitted form after clicking ok in the alert box

Tags: javascript

I have a form

onclick confirm , i need to direct it to a particular url

```
function submitdata() { 
     if(confirm("Are You Sure You Want To Proceed?")) {
        location.replace("http://www.w3schools.com");
    } else { 
        alert("Cancelling"); 
    }

}
</script>
```

After submitting this form submitdata() is called.

then i am getting an alert.

BUT MY FORM is not getting redirected

```
<form id="registration_form" action="" method="post" onsubmit="return submitdata();">

        <div id="state"></div>


         <div class="reg-id">
            <label>
                <input placeholder="State:" type="text" tabindex="3" name="user_state" id="reg_state" value="">
            </label>

        </div>

        <div class="reg-id">
            <label>
                <input placeholder="City:" type="text" tabindex="3" name="user_city" id="reg_city" value="">
            </label>
        </div>

         <div class="reg-id-last">
            <label>
                <input placeholder="Zip/Postal:" type="text" tabindex="3" name="user_zip" id="reg_zip" value="">
            </label>
        </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Response" tabindex="3" name="reg_btn" id="id-submit">
        </div>

    </form>
```

Comment: you're not getting redirected because you're returning true; so the code after that will not execute.

Comment: remove the `return true; ` and it will start working

Comment: By using `return` you stop execution of the code inside the function. If you just want to redirect, remove the `return true;` statement. If you want to submit the  form data to the redirected page, then use Ajax instead.

Comment: i removed return true, but its not getting redirected

Comment: try doing `location.href = 'http://www.w3schools.com';`

Comment: You will have to use AJAX or JQuery in order to submit form data and then redirrect to another page if form is submitted to different webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it

```
<script>

    function submitdata() { 
       var r = confirm('Are you sure?');

        if (r == true) {

            window.open('http://www.google.com');
        } else {
            alert('it didnt work');
        }
        return false;         

    }
    </script>
```

Comment: if you just wanted to open a new window, you should have said so. your question says `javascript Redirect ` and you're doing a `window.open`. both are two different things. keep your question clear next time.

Answer (score 2):

```
 if(confirm("Are You Sure You Want To Proceed?")) {
    return true; 
    location.replace("http://www.w3schools.com");
 }
```

`return` returns from the surrounding function. Nothing after it will be executed. You need to swap the two lines.

Comment: the line after retur would not be executed

Answer (score -1):

If you want the form to actually submit to that location, then the form data won't get sent with that redirect. You can submit the data by setting the `action` attribute of your `form` tag to the URL you want, and changing the form submit event to something like this:

```
function submitData(event) {
  if(confirm('Are you sure you want to proceed?') == false){
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
}
```

So instead of redirecting when the user clicks 'ok', you basically just cancel the form submit if the user doesn't click 'ok'.

If you didn't want to submit the data, then you just need to move your return statement, like melpomene suggested.

Note: I always write both `event.preventDefault()` and `return false;` but I think usually only `return false;` would work as well. But, better safe than sorry :)